# Which classification metrics does Scikit's learn Random Forest classifier 'score' method uses?

Tags: scikit-learn

The documentation (http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.score) mentions the method returns the 'mean accuracy', but how is the accuracy calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the [accuracy score](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/model_evaluation.html#accuracy-score), also know as one minus the  0-1 error. (thanks lars)

Comment: Also known as *one minus* the mean 0-1 loss.